# Adding multiple rules for indicators SSRS BIDS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have produced a report which allows you to drill down into the table you see with ticks and crosses. Each tick indicates that a task is complete. In the second picture you can see the rules which dictate whether the task is classes as complete or incomplete and they are the following:

If Remaining Hours = 0 then the task is complete and therfore a tick appears.
If Remaining Hours is between 0.01 and 1,000,000 then there is still work to be carried out and therfore the task is not complete.

The oversight on this the 'Total Effort' column, if this is 0.00 and remaining Hours is also 0.00 then it means that the task has not began yet and is therfore incomplete however due to my rules, a tick is appearing next to these unstarted tasks.

My question is, how do I add a second ruling to take into account 'Total Effort' because as far as I can see I am only able to select one value from the drop down box and then populate just for that.

The rules need to be:
If Remaining Hours = 0 and Total Effort >= 0.01 then a green tick
If Remaining Hours is between 0.01 and 1,000,000 then a red cross
If Total Effort = 0.00 and Remaining Hours = 0.00, then red cross

Hope this makes sense.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=iif(Sum(Fields!EffortRemaining.Value) =0 and Sum(Fields!TotalEffort.Value) >= 0.01,1,0) for value expression

Then tell red cross for 0 and green tick for 1